# Is there any way to use MongoSourceConnector for multiple database with single kafka topic?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am using MongoSourceConnector to connect kafka topic with mongo database collection. For single database with single kafka topic it's working fine, but is there any way that i could do a connection for multiple mongo database with single kafka topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running kafka-connect in distributed mode then you can create a another connector config file with the above mentioned config

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure about multiple databases and a single Kafka topic but you can surely listen to multiple databases [change streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/source-connector/usage-examples/multiple-sources/) and push data to topics. Since topic creation depends on the `database_name.collection_name`, so you will have more topics.

You can provide the Regex to listen to multiple databases in the `pipeline`.

```json
"pipeline": "[{\"$match\":{\"$and\":[{\"ns.db\":{\"$regex\":/^database-names_.*/}},{\"ns.coll\":{\"$regex\":/^collection_name$/}}]}}]"
```

Here is the complete Kafka connector configuration.

***Mongo to Kafka source connector***

```json
{
  "name": "mongo-to-kafka-connect",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "publish.full.document.only": "true",
    "tasks.max": "3",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "topic.creation.enable": "true",
    "poll.await.time.ms": 1000,
    "poll.max.batch.size": 100,
    "topic.prefix": "any prefix for topic name",
    "output.json.formatter": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.SimplifiedJson",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://<username>:<password>@ip:27017,ip:27017,ip:27017,ip:27017/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=xyz&tls=true",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "copy.existing": "true",
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": 3,
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": 3,
    "topic.creation.compacted.cleanup.policy": "compact",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "mongo.errors.log.enable": "true",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms": 10000,
    "pipeline": "[{\"$match\":{\"$and\":[{\"ns.db\":{\"$regex\":/^database-names_.*/}},{\"ns.coll\":{\"$regex\":/^collection_name$/}}]}}]"
  }
}
```

You can get more details from official docs.

- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/source-connector/
- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/index.html